# Will an external GPU fix my GPU kernel panic?

Tags: graphics-card, macbook, gpu, kernel-panic

I have an early 2013 Macbook Pro 15". My graphics card has become faulty (like many of these models macbook models, that were shipped with faulty cards), I've also unfortunately missed the Extension program.

My question is, if I plug in an external GPU will this prevent the onboard card from firing and thus prevent the unwanted restarts that I'm experiencing?

Link: https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Comment: Which GPU is faulty the Nvidia ?

Comment: Yep that's correct, nvidia gefore gt 650m

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the OS boots on **intel iGPU** and activates the **e-GPU** when needed instead of using the Nvidia GT, as seen in [780 Ti in MBP Late '16](https://egpu.io/forums/implementation-guides/late-2016-13-mbp-gtx780-ti32gbps-tb3-akitio-thunder3-macos-10-12-3-ikir/) the problem will be fixed.